# Whats is proper version of llvm/clang/xcode?

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, c++17, llvm-clang

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292) mentions that xcode 9 published with 'Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)', but the last version of llvm in [llvm.org](http://releases.llvm.org/) is LLVM 5.0.0.
What is the relation between them?

Comment: [LLVM Compiler Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/index.html)

Comment: @Desdenova I read them. but still no answer! what is the relation between clang 5 and clang-900?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's Xcode ship with LLVM, but it is not the open source version. For example, some clang extra tool won't be installed to you Mac. So at least, Apple has modify `CMakeLists.txt`. You can read the `CMakeLists.txt` or `Makefile` in [apple open source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/llvmCore/llvmCore-3425.0.36/).

This is only a suggestion, maybe is not helpful.

Another: [index.file](https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete/commit/bd2eaef71883b4323a5ce7a55e33ab7ed000fb6f) shows Xcode LLVM 9 map to Clang/LLVM 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the source code for the compiler shipped with Xcode from https://opensource.apple.com if you want to have the exact same version of LLVM.