# How can I build a clang plugin that will be compatible with Apple's shipped clang?

Tags: xcode, clang

The latest version of clang, as shipped with xcode, is clang-900.0.39.2.

Since the source code for this build does not seem to be available publicly, is there any way to write a clang plugin that can be loaded and executed by that version of clang?

Comment: You want to build your own clang analyser or you want to use external clang api with your Xcode project?

Comment: A clang analyzer. That is, code that analyzes the AST produced by clang.

Comment: Maybe this helps [Whats is proper version of llvm/clang/xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46955807/598057).

Comment: I see two options: 1) to find which version clang-900.0.39.2 is built with and try building your own clang analyzer with it. 2) if possible, take the latest clang, build both analyzer and clang using it and run them without Apple's shipped clang (if this makes sense to your context).

Comment: Maybe this helps then: [How can I force Xcode to use a custom compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327952/how-can-i-force-xcode-to-use-a-custom-compiler/43355809#43355809).